# Initializing long nested structures in C

Tags: c, memory-management

What is the best/cleanest way to initialize (in a local function) a long chain of nested structures when each structure contains only pointers to other structures, like so:

```
typedef struct A{
struct B{
    struct C *c /* OPTIONAL */;
    struct D *d /* OPTIONAL */;
    struct E *e /* OPTIONAL */;
    struct F *f /* OPTIONAL */;
} *b;
struct G{
    struct F *f /* OPTIONAL */;
    struct D *d /* OPTIONAL */;
    struct H *h /* OPTIONAL */;
    struct F *f /* OPTIONAL */;
} *g;
    } a;
```

Each of the pointers to the nested structures themselves point to structures containing pointers to other nested structures (I know, its crazy!)

I figure that I need to define a tmp pointer for each struct member and allocate memory for it and also a tmp struct variable and point the former to the latter:

```
B *b_ptr = CALLOC(1,sizeof(b_ptr));
B b_tmp;
b_ptr = &b_tmp;
b_tmp.itsMember1 = CALLOC(1,sizeof(itsMember1));
TypeOfItsMember1 itsMember1_tmp;
..
..
```

This will require scores of local variables and painfully repetitive coding. Is there a better way to initialize the parent struct completely?

Any experts in the house care to give their 2 cents?

Answer (score 1):

You could start off by writing a set of functions that allocated and initialized the various nested structures.

```
struct C *NewC(int f1, int f2, ...)
{
    struct C *result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
    result->f1 = f1;
    result->f2 = f2;
    .....
    return result;
}
```

And do likewise for your other structs.

Then you can use these building blocks in concert with standard struct initializers:

```
struct B b = {
    NewC(42, 666, ...),
    NULL, 
    NULL,
    NewF(....)
};
```

If you want to allocate your `struct B` on the heap instead of the stack, then you could write a `NewB` function in similar vein.

The advantage of this approach is that if you ever add fields to your struct, you can just add extra parameter to the `NewX` function and any clients of that struct will be forced by the compiler to provide the extra parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just realized that I could create a new flat structure with the combined parameters of all nested structures and pass its reference to the init function. Then just allocate memory for each nested structure and assign the pointers to the respective parameters in the created structure.
The issue with defining init functions is that there are some cases where a nested structure contains just a pointer to another structure and nothing else. So defining an init function for this does not make sense. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion; it definitely set me thinking..

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- Adopt a serialization scheme so that you can read a graph of structures in from a file.
- If it's not too late, consider using a language like Java or C++ so that you can work in terms of classes and objects instead of structures. This simplifies the problem because each "structure" can then initialize itself.
- Even if you can't switch to a more object-oriented language, you can still use a more object-oriented approach. Break the problem down by writing functions that initialize each structure and sub-structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you direct me to some references for the first point?

Comment: @user837483 Absent any requirements, I'd probably think about using XML first. You can use [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/index.html) to do the parsing, and then you'll just need to write the code that translates the values you find into your structures.